# How to link Extensal CSS files and link external image paths in css files?

Tags: javascript, css, links, image-path

When i use EE's internal CSS template, the css works fine.

But i have decided to take the css and javascripts out of ee templates and keep them in their own separate folders at the root of EE installation.

Here is my structure:

- root

  - assets

    - scripts
    - styles
  - images
  - system
  - themes

This is the code in my index.html header area

#### (1st Try)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{path='assets/styles/style.css'}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{path='assets/styles/color.css'}" media="all" />
```

#### (2nd Try)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}assets/styles/inner.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}assets/styles/flexslider.css" />
```

Here are the

```
#selector{ background:url({site_url}images/front/top-pattern.png);}
```

### Note:

**The css files are loaded correctly in HTML but the images are not loaded.**

I checked with firbug and it says

> Failed to load the given URL

The issue is with the image path inside the css files.

I cant figure out what am i missing ?

Comment: UPDATE :

Its works if i use absolute URL's: 

> #selector{ background:url(http://www.domain.com/images/front/top-pattern.png);}

It still does not work with site_url or path

Answer (score 3):

EE won't parse tags that are stored outside of templates unless you do some trickery to send them back into the parser.

Keep them in templates if you need the tags parsed. Though I should note that the parsing abilities for CSS and Javascript templates seem limited.

While you are at it be sure to look into a minimizing module, this doesn't solve your problem but they are useful for speeding up your site and combining css/js files. I use Automin, there's another called Minimee.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into Minimee.

I wanted to use Sass, would it possible to use it when having css as EE templates ?

Comment: Yes. Both can parse from EE templates thought it's not a requirement. I use EE templates for CSS because I like to grant access via the panel and it allows for revision tracking. I had to modify Automin to work properly for some reason though, I forget what I did :(

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid anything based on {site_url} and opt for relative paths instead. With what you've supplied, simply placing an "/" instead of {site_url} would suffice.

That being said I would also avoid placing css in a template and do it the old fashioned way to stop this errant behaviour which also gives the added benefit of making solving any css issue, that much easier because you've removed it from ee control.

Comment: I actually did try it with "/" flash in the front but with same result as above.

So how do we resolve this issue of having the css and javascripts outside of the ee template structure.

I wonder if it worth all the hassle in the first place.

Comment: /assets/styles/style.css always works on my end. Perhaps you are working in a dev setup that won't support a root relative path?

Comment: I am working on my localhost dev environment.

Comment: I would like to highlight that the index.html file is picking up my css files and javascripts files just fine with the {site_url} variable. 

The issue is with the image paths inside the css files, if use the {site_url} var or path var, it does not work.

Comment: I usually use site-root relative links too and it works fine for me. If you're on localhost you'll probably need to set a named virtual host in your hosts file.

Comment: Ibn, if you don't already know relative paths (non root relative i.e. "/" or non absolute i.e. http://) you put in a .css file are relative to that .css file whereas if you put them in your index.html (which I don't know why you keep calling it .html) it will be relative to the index.html file. It looks a bit like you need to brush up on your understanding of paths though. EE is just going to output whatever path you tell it to, it's up to you to determine if what you told it is what correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS file isn't being parsed by EECMS, using the `path` variable, you can't use variables or snippets on it.

This **isn't** an EECMS issue.

Since the image directory isn't a sibling of your CSS directory (`/assets/styles`), but a sibling of its parent (`/assets`), you need to go up to levels on your image paths.

```
#selector{ background:url(../../images/front/top-pattern.png); }
```

The first `../` goes up to the `assets` folder. The second goes one level up, to the `root` folder. Just then you can go down to the `images` folder.